# Can we parameterize a glide.yaml file?

Tags: go, glide-golang

This is the glide.yaml file from the official documentation

```
package: github.com/Masterminds/glide
homepage: https://masterminds.github.io/glide
license: MIT
owners:
- name: Matt Butcher
  email: technosophos@gmail.com
homepage: http://technosophos.com
- name: Matt Farina
email: matt@mattfarina.com
homepage: https://www.mattfarina.com
ignore:
- appengine
excludeDirs:
- node_modules
import:
- package: gopkg.in/yaml.v2
- package: github.com/Masterminds/vcs
  version: ^1.2.0
  repo:    git@github.com:Masterminds/vcs
  vcs:     git
- package: github.com/codegangsta/cli
  version: f89effe81c1ece9c5b0fda359ebd9cf65f169a51
- package: github.com/Masterminds/semver
  version: ^1.0.0
testImport:
- package: github.com/arschles/assert
```

If I want to parameterize repo, like store it in a variable in a util file or in an environment variable and fetch it from there in the glide.yaml file ? Is it possible to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

No. This is not supported. You can see everything that *is* supported in the glide.yaml file in the [official documentation](https://glide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/glide.yaml/).